# How do I make an image semi-transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, photoshop

Suppose I have an image that is a black circle PNG. (transparent background, black circle in middle)

I want to place this black circle on top of some text, but I want to make it semi-transparent. How can I do that in CSS, or photoshop? Or what?

Comment: My folks are truck drivers (really) and trust me, you don't want to be transparent to a semi. They hurt. ( sorry I couldn't help myself :X )

Comment: bear in mind that placing the image over the text is probably a bad idea as it will interfere with the users ability to select the text and click links within the text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I might do it.

**See a working example at jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/MxQTz/2/

**HTML**

```
<p class="text">
  Here is some text. This will be displayed beneath the black circle.
  Here is some text. This will be displayed beneath the black circle.
  <span class="circle"></span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #eee;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.text .circle {
    background-image: url("http://nontalk.s3.amazonaws.com/black-circle.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /* Here's where you set the opacity */
    opacity: .5;

    /* Here's where you set the opacity for the bad browser */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the here is where you set the opacity for the bad browser comment. Well played sir!

Comment: Did you try this on the "bad" browser? Does not appear to work.

Answer (score 3):

In CSS just use:

```
img {
    opacity: value;
}
```

Needs to be a value 0-1. 0 is completely transparent, 1 is opaque, 0.5 would be average. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put jQuery on your site and write this:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {   
      $("div.circle").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why have the overhead of jquery when you can just do it with css? And all that is doing is just changing the css property anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use css property opacity = 0.5; filter:alpha 50 for IE;

Comment: might want to use -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; for IE8 even though filter is supposed to be supported too

Comment: you need to put it on top of a text?? Then you might need to consider some z-index and use absolute position. see overlapping position in http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp . By the way , you might want to consider canvas.

Answer (score 0):

In photoshop keep the circle above the text layer. then select the circle layer & in layer options reduce its transparency by dragging the slider. OR simply press numbers on the num pad of keyboard 0= full opaque, 9=10 % opacity & so on....